# How to print the 1398th prime number in python?

Tags: python

hey guys i'm newbie please tell me how to make this code work to print the 1398th prime number.
https://code.sololearn.com/c1a3lvSiIF9w/?ref=app

```
#newbie
def IsPrime(X):
  IsPrime = 1
  for i in range(2):
    if i < X:
      if X % i == 0:
        IsPrime = 0
        if IsPrime == 0:
          print ("X Is Prime")
        else:
          print ("X Is Not Prime")
      else:
        i = i + 1
    else:
      if IsPrime == 0:
        print ("X Is Prime")
      else:
        print ("X Is Not Prime")
#newbie

for i in range(2):
  C = 0
  if C < 1398:
    if IsPrime(i) == 1:
      C = C + 1
      i = i + 1
    else:
      i = i + 1
  else:
    print (i - 1)
#newbie
```

Comment: Just a remark: Never name a variable with the name of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few errors with your code structre. Ive also tried to make your code a little cleaner. Try to follow the PEP8 python style guide, it helps with making code more readable and understandable to others.

This should do the trick:

```
def IsPrime(X):
    count = 0
    for i in range(X):
        if X % (i + 1) == 0:
            count = count + 1
    if count == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def findPrime(n):
    count = 0
    i = 1
    while count < n:
        if IsPrime(i) == True:
            count = count + 1
        i = i + 1
    return i - 1

print (findPrime(1398))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with reasonably small numbers, the following algorithm will find first `N` primes:

```
N = 1398

primes = [1]
n = primes[-1]
while len(primes) < N:
    n, d = n + 1, None
    for p in primes:
        if p > 1 and n % p == 0:
            d = p
            break
    if not d:
        primes.append(n)

# first 10 primes
print(primes[:10])

# 1398-th prime
print(primes[-1])
```

What does it do?

- start with some known primes (no one missing from that range)
- let `n` be the last prime plus one
- let `d` be any known prime `p` but 1 dividing `n`
- if no `d` was found, `n` is prime
- stop after finding `N` primes